# KafkaStreams Table - Table inner join produces duplicates

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, apache-kafka-streams

My application needs to perform a join between two kafka topics using kafka streams. We used to model one as a KStream (left) and one KTable (right) and do a leftJoin, but we found many times the join resulted in a null right value which wasn't desired behaviour. A windowed join on 2 streams is also problematic for our use case. So now we model both as KTable and do an inner join, then consume that stream to generate our business logic.
But unexpectedly I find that firing 1 message on each of the input topics with the same key actually causes 2 joins to happen, resulting in 2 identical messages on the result stream.

I wrote a unit test using TestTopologyDriver and I got the right behaviour (1 result message per pair), but when running with TestCompanion and a test broker or indeed running the application, I get the duplicates.

Our streams app is inside Quarkus 2.16.x with Streams 3.3.2, with config set as

```
kafka-streams.cache.max.bytes.buffering=10240
kafka-streams.commit.interval.ms=500
kafka-streams.metadata.max.age.ms=500
kafka-streams.auto.offset.reset=earliest
kafka-streams.consumer.heartbeat.interval.ms=200
```

The described topology below (ignore the node numbers start at 41, below is self encapsulated). Sub topology 1 allows 1 input message to arrive on the 2 input topics for ease of testing. Sub topology 2 makes them both KTables then does inner join. Actually I noticed same duplicate behaviour with outer join also (once I filtered out the null left/right values)

```
Sub-topology: 1
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000041 (topics: [trigger])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000044, KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000042
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000044 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000045
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000041
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000042 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000043
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000041
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000045 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000046
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000044
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000043 (topic: value)
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000042
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000046 (topic: state)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000045

  Sub-topology: 2
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000047 (topics: [value])
      --> KSTREAM-TOTABLE-0000000048
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000051 (topics: [state])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000052
    Processor: KSTREAM-TOTABLE-0000000048 (stores: [KSTREAM-TOTABLE-STATE-STORE-0000000049])
      --> KTABLE-JOINOTHER-0000000055
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000047
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000052 (stores: [status-STATE-STORE-0000000050])
      --> KTABLE-JOINTHIS-0000000054
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000051
    Processor: KTABLE-JOINOTHER-0000000055 (stores: [status-STATE-STORE-0000000050])
      --> KTABLE-MERGE-0000000053
      <-- KSTREAM-TOTABLE-0000000048
    Processor: KTABLE-JOINTHIS-0000000054 (stores: [KSTREAM-TOTABLE-STATE-STORE-0000000049])
      --> KTABLE-MERGE-0000000053
      <-- KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000052
    Processor: KTABLE-MERGE-0000000053 (stores: [])
      --> KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000056
      <-- KTABLE-JOINTHIS-0000000054, KTABLE-JOINOTHER-0000000055
    Processor: KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000056 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000057
      <-- KTABLE-MERGE-0000000053
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000057 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000058
      <-- KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000056
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000058 (topic: joined)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000057
```

I saw some post which suggested I needed to write a de-duplicating processor on the result stream, but that seems a bit weird since I'd need to maintain a 3rd store? Besides I can't see in the documentation why processing happens twice. If it does have a bearing on it, the arrival of messages with same key on the 2 input topics is likely to be very close together time wise (i.e. within a few milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

> But unexpectedly I find that firing 1 message on each of the input topics with the same key actually causes 2 joins to happen, resulting in 2 identical messages on the result stream.

That is the expected behavior of the `join` operator in Kafka streams. Using `join` operator, a join will be triggered when a new record is received, regardless of the side it was received from.

If that is not what you are looking for, you can use `leftJoin` instead.